# How to open latest created folder on FTP server in python

Tags: python, automation, scripting

I want to open latest created folder on FTP server using python.
Basically I want to automate the downloading process i.e whenever I run script it goes into latest created folder and download the files. Files created can be seen on image.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, welcome to SO! Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Basically, you should attempt to solve your problem, post your code, and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Maybe just use a synchronize tool.Synchronize in ftp filezilla.